# Скачиваю масив даных стран и городов, ошибка:No such file or directory: 'city.list.json.gz'.через сылку вы качаете файл json,бот по игре в города

Tags: json, gzip

```
import requests
```

## Замените 'YOUR_API_KEY' на ваш собственный API ключ

api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

## Запрос на получение списка городов на русском языке

url = f"http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz"  # Откройте эту ссылку для скачивания файла

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:

```
import json
import gzip

with gzip.open("city.list.json.gz", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

russian_cities = [city['name'] for city in data if city['lang'] == 'ru']
# Выведите список городов или сохраните его в файл
print(russian_cities)
```

else:
print("Произошла ошибка при получении данных.")

Comment: не может найти файл. Мне надо вывести только один элемент 'name'  это города. имя файла точно правильное

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'city.list.json.gz'

Comment: У вас перед URL вкралась ошибка — буква "f".

Comment: Нет, это буква не на что не влияет, спасибо

Comment: Имя-то может и правильное, но расположение файла может отличаться. Проверь, что совпадает путь, по которому сохраняется скачанный файл, и путь для чтения этого скачанного файла.

Comment: Nikolai Shevchenko сможете пожалуйста по подробнее объяснить